# How to use reflection to get the number of items in a list

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I have a class that has a few `List<T>` properties.  I need to be able to dynamically determine the size of a given list.

Below is the code that I have so far.  How can I get rid of the switch statement and just have this as one general statement?  I would love to cast to `List<T>`, but that doesn't work.

```
switch (Inf.GetType()
            .GetProperty(propertyName)
            .GetValue(Inf)
            .GetType()
            .UnderlyingSystemType.GenericTypeArguments[0]
            .Name)
        {
            case "String":
                dynamicListCount = ((List<string>)Inf.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(Inf)).Count;
                break;
            case "Int32":
                dynamicListCount = ((List<Int32>)Inf.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(Inf)).Count;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown list type");
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you cast as `IList`?

Comment: Not sure why you don't use `List<T>`.Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` implements `IList` which has a `Count` property (inherited from `ICollection`).

You can simply cast the value as `IList` and get the count like this:

```
IList list = (IList) Inf.GetType()
        .GetProperty(propertyName)
        .GetValue(Inf);

var count = list.Count;
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried casting to IList.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should typecast it to `IList` because the generic typed `List<>` implements the interface `IList`. Same like the comment is suggesting. (crosspost)

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();

items.Add("item1");
items.Add("item2");


int count = ((IList)items).Count;

MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```